# Can't add a service reference

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf-data-services, ado.net-entity-data-model

I built a Solution that has to projects:

- ASP NET Empty Web Application
- WPF Application

The ASP NET App includes a WCF Data Service (which I named MyServiceServer) and an Entity Data Model generated from a SQL Server Express database (which I named MiniNorthwind, basically Northwind but with integer table keys and Foreign key relationships)

When I try to add a Service Reference to my WPF App (of the service that's located in the ASP Net app of the same solution), I use Discover, but it throws an error>

[image]

At the end of the error it suggest to try to rebuild the service, then I delete and add the whole service again several times until it is added successfully.

The problem is that somehow it loses configuration and the problem reappears when I run the whole app.

I included the app in [SkyDrive MyServiceSolutionInIIS](https://skydrive.live.com/?mkt=en-US#cid=228822BB183339A9&id=228822BB183339A9!234) along with a backup of the MiniNorthwind database.

What could it be?

Comment: Is your service started? It has to be running first.

Comment: The problem was that I enabled ASP NET Impersonation in IIS Manager. I did it because I have being trying to make it work and I keep getting "Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\Servicio de red" ("Servicio de red" is NETWORKSERVICE), I'm trying everything!!

Comment: So, does it work when you use no authentication?

Comment: What do you mean with "No Authentication"?

Comment: In IIS Manager, click on the site or application, then double click on "Authentication". One option is "Anonymous Authentication". Make sure that it is enabled, and that the other types are disabled. Now try accessing your service and see what happens.

Comment: I already found what the problem was, ASP Impersonation has to be disabled.

Comment: Turn your comment into an answer in order to mark it

Comment: But you already found the answer. I recommend that you answer your own question with the details of what you found and how you found it. Then you can mark that as the answer, and perhaps even get upvotes for it. That will best help others who may have the same problem.

Comment: @Rafael please answer this post with your solution, then mark it as answered (so we don't keep seeing this as unanswered :). Thanks!